# SD card not detected through a USB hub on an intel-based Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, sd-card

This is my first time trying out an SD card via a USB hub on my Mac (since there's no port for SD card on current portable Macs) and I can't seem to detect the SD card; it doesn't show in disk utility and nor in Finder.

[image: This is a photo of my setup]

Does anyone know what could potentially be the cause?

Comment: Does the card reader show in the USB section in the system report?

Comment: system report? you mean disk utility?

Comment: just verified. yeah I see `USB3.0 Card Reader` under `USB3.1 Hub` Why do I not see it in disk utils or finder then?

Answer (score 1):

You won't see it in disk utils or finder until it is mounted. The primary causes of this are (in my experience):

1. Inadequate power in the USB-C hub. Typically, power needs to pass through the hub rather than the hub being a stub. (Sorry, couldn't resist the rhyme). I *think* I saw the hub plugged in by itself...
   Now, that said, with nothing else, that shouldn't be a problem, but try it. It's quite common with USB hard drives that are USB powered.
2. Bad connection or damaged card. Check the card contacts, make sure they are clean and undamaged.
3. A corrupted card (or a card image that looks corrupted due to 1 or 2). Check to see if an fsck process is running on the card; this is done for 'dirty' disk images that aren't known to be cleanly ejected. It won't mount until that completes. If the process is hung, or dies repeatedly, then it's likely that it's having a hard time reading the card, again, see 1 and 2. If it's hung, kill it, and eject the card and try again.

Comment: other ports of the USB hub do work though so I guess power may not be an issue. how do I run `fsck` on the SD card if I don't even see in diskutil and I don't know its port number?

Comment: Or presumably 4. The partition(s) are in format(s) that macOS can't mount?